# Globally Lipschitz continuous IVP, approximating a solution with $0<x(0)<1$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

I'm trying to solve this question and I have done it but with $0 \leq x(t) \leq 1$ at the end. Using that f is Lipschitz continuous we know that the solution can't cross and diverge, but it could in theory converge together. Why is this not the case here?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Substitute $u(t)=x-t^2$, it should greatly simplify the equation.

Comment: @LutzL Thanks, so this turns it into an autonomous equation which cannot cross.

Comment: Yes, the stationary solutions of the autonomous equation can not be crossed.